# How to display an image in local by angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I need to display an image in angularjs(File in local). by
`<img src="imagename.jpg"> and <img ng-src={{imagename.jpg}}`

this two methonds. i cant display it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your second example wouldn't work because it is trying to data-bind from `$scope`. Angular things of that as `$scope.imagename.jpg`, which is not what you want to do :) Does your console show any errors?

Comment: It doesn't show any errors.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably getting an error with `$sce` in which the image source is not trusted.

Just pass the `$sce` service as a dependency and use `trustAsResourceUrl` so that Angular will not throw the error.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.myImgSrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('path/to/img.jpg');
});
```

You can then use the $scope property as the img src like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{myImgSrc}}">
```

Comment: thanks. But what i should include in html file for this script.

Comment: Its not working :(. `html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <img ng-src="{{myImgSrc}}">
 </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: `var myapp=angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.myImgSrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('/Abc_Mobiles/assets/www/partials/345i0iwf.jpg');
});` This is my code.

Comment: @user3110587 Saying "it's not working" isn't enough information. What isn't working? Inspect the element on the page, is the src set? Are there errors in the console? Also, you mentioned in your edit that using the img tag directly doesn't work. If that's the case, your error probably doesn't have to do with angular. It sounds you like you have server or file problem. Can you make a demo on jsbin?

Comment: When i upload it to server. It wont work. Only works when i give it as markup.

Comment: Is this working at all? One thing I wonder is what is the full path because you didn't specify it from a drive?

Comment: @miliu I gave up on trying to help because the OP doesn't give specific enough information about the problem. My answer here is the best I could guess about what his problem is.